# Triggers not working in multibranch pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have added triggers to my multibranch pipe line and it is not running on a schedule. Sample pipeline script

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'xxxx' }
    triggers {
        cron('H * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage("Stage 123"){
            steps {
                echo "test"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add a trigger in a Jenkinsfile from SCM, the Jenkins job has to be run at least once in order for Jenkins to pick up on the trigger to even know it needs to periodically check.